# System have strong enough statistics?

Tags: animation

is my system strong enough to run most animations. Seem to be having problems rendering
Intel 3.2 GHz
4GB RAM
with nvidia 610

Comment: It all depends on the kinds and complexity of the scenesl you are dealing with. This kind of questions are hard to answer properly. You might find better answers in the technical support forum at http://blenderartists.org/forum/

Comment: thank you. i had a laptop before today and it seemed to render both still and animations alot faster than this pc, all though this pc has faster processor and a graphics card. the lap top only had more ram. 6 instead of 4. wondering if certain settings are needed to be changed and im missing them.

Comment: 4Gb of RAM might be too low, depending on the scene...